# add icon to error message using php session

Tags: php

I have this class for show error with `session` method using PHP.

```
class Messages {

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Class Variables
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
    var $msgId;
    var $msgTypes = array( 'help', 'info', 'warning', 'success', 'danger' );
    var $msgClass = 'alert';
    var $msgWrapper = " <div class='alert %s-%s flashit'>
    <button class='close' aria-hidden='true' data-dismiss='alert' type='button'>×</button>
    <p><i style='vertical-align: middle;' class='%s icon-2x'></i> %s</p>
    </div>";
    var $msgBefore = '';
    var $msgAfter = "";

    public function __construct() {

        // Generate a unique ID for this user and session
        $this->msgId = md5(uniqid());

        // Create the session array if it doesnt already exist
        if( !array_key_exists('flash_messages', $_SESSION) ) $_SESSION['flash_messages'] = array();

    }

    public function add($type, $message, $redirect_to=null) {

        if( !isset($_SESSION['flash_messages']) ) return false;

        if( !isset($type) || !isset($message[0]) ) return false;

        // Replace any shorthand codes with their full version
        if( strlen(trim($type)) == 1 ) {
            $type = str_replace( array('h', 'i', 'w', 'e', 's'), array('help', 'info', 'warning', 'danger', 'success'), $type );
            $icon = str_replace( array('h', 'i', 'w', 'e', 's'), array('fa-help', 'fa-info', 'fa-warning', 'fa-danger', 'fa-success'), $type );
        // Backwards compatibility...
        } elseif( $type == 'information' ) {
            $type = 'info';
            $icon = 'fa-info';      
        }


        // Make sure it's a valid message type
        if( !in_array($type, $this->msgTypes) ) die('"' . strip_tags($type) . '" is not a valid message type!' );

        // If the session array doesn't exist, create it
        if( !array_key_exists( $type, $_SESSION['flash_messages'] ) ) $_SESSION['flash_messages'][$type] = array();

        $_SESSION['flash_messages'][$type][] = $message;

        if( !is_null($redirect_to) ) {
            header("Location: $redirect_to");
            exit();
        }

        return true;

    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // display()
    // print queued messages to the screen
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function display($type='all', $print=true) {
        $messages = '';
        $data = '';

        if( !isset($_SESSION['flash_messages']) ) return false;

        if( $type == 'g' || $type == 'growl' ) {
            $this->displayGrowlMessages();
            return true;
        }

        // Print a certain type of message?
        if( in_array($type, $this->msgTypes) ) {
            foreach( $_SESSION['flash_messages'][$type] as $msg ) {
                $messages .= $this->msgBefore . $msg . $this->msgAfter;
            }

            $data .= sprintf($this->msgWrapper, $this->msgClass, $type,$icon,$messages);

            // Clear the viewed messages
            $this->clear($type);

        // Print ALL queued messages
        } elseif( $type == 'all' ) {
            foreach( $_SESSION['flash_messages'] as $type => $msgArray ) {
                $messages = '';

                foreach( $msgArray as $msg ) {
                    $messages .= $this->msgBefore . $msg . $this->msgAfter; 
                }
                $data .= sprintf($this->msgWrapper, $this->msgClass, $type,$icon,$messages);
            }

            // Clear ALL of the messages
            $this->clear();

        // Invalid Message Type?
        } else { 
            return false;
        }

        // Print everything to the screen or return the data
        if( $print ) { 
            echo $data; 
        } else { 
            return $data; 
        }
    }

  //..... more
}
```

Call:

```
$msg = new Messages();
$msg->add('i', 'This is a Information message!');
echo $msg->display();
```

Now in Output:

```
<i style="vertical-align: middle;" class=" icon-2x"></i>
```

Icon class not printed and empty: `class=" icon-2x"`. how do can i fix this ?

**EDit:** Indeed i need to print for each type One class name.

Comment: TBH, I'm not entirely sure. Probably the space in there is making the class invalid, and should read as `class="icon-2x"`. Try removing the space in `class='%s icon-2x'` as in `class='%sicon-2x'`

Comment: Plus, since you are using sessions, you have started it, yes?

Comment: @Fred-ii-: space generate with class for $icon ie: `fa-info`. my problem is: i need to print icon class name with $icon array. But in ouput i see space.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Sure, This class Worked True for me. Only i cant print icon name !! see this line : `$icon = str_replace( array('h', 'i', 'w', 'e', 's'), array('fa-help', 'fa-info', 'fa-warning', 'fa-danger', 'fa-success'), $type );` and `$data .= sprintf($this->msgWrapper, $this->msgClass, $type,$icon,$messages);`

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Indeed i need to print for each type One class icon.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you are storing the `$icon` value anywhere. It only exists in the `add` function. Did you try to add it as a `class variable`?

Comment: @RST: no i don't try to this. you have this idea?

Comment: add it to your class variables at the top of the code and refer to it as `$this->icon` in the rest of your code.